# Is there a standard way to do `actorFor orElse actorOf`?

Tags: akka

I would like to get an `ActorRef` that may already have been created. Is there a standard way to call `context.actorFor` and, only if it didn't return a live `ActorRef`, call `context.actorOf`? Vice versa is also fine (ie call `context.actorOf` and, only if the actor already exists, call `context.actorFor`).

Answer (score 6):

First off: get-or-create can only work if there is exactly one entity which does it (otherwise you will never be sure how it was created when you find it). This means that the parent of the actor-to-be is the place to put this code.

Within an actor it is quite straight-forward:

```scala
val child =
  context.child(name) match {
    case None    => context.actorOf(Props(...), name)
    case Some(c) => c
  }
```

Please refrain from using `actorFor`, it is deprecated in Akka 2.2 for [good reason](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/project/migration-guide-2.1.x-2.2.x.html#Use_actorSelection_instead_of_actorFor). In this case `context.child()` does what you want more efficiently.

Comment: or: val child = context.child(name).getOrElse(context.actorOf(Props(…), name))

Comment: I thought `context.child` was for Java API?

Comment: Why would you think that? And why would that invalidate our advice?