# Get child actors of all members of an actor pool

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I have a round robin pool of actors, which connect to some remote system and create processor actors to actually process them. I want to get-or-create processors by their names using context.child (as per [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701232/is-there-a-standard-way-to-do-actorfor-orelse-actorof)). But to my understanding this won't work due to the following situation:

1. There's a pool of connectors `{A, B}`.
2. `A` accepts message `A1` and creates child processor `AA`.
3. `B` accepts message `A2`, tries to get child `BA`, cannot do this and creates it, thus ruining consistency of `AA` internal state.

Is there any way to get "shared children" semantics, besides using `system.actorFor`? As far as I understand, it and `actorSelection` use recursive path resolving from the root, so by using it I will waste resources on resolving `{A, B}` for each request.

Comment: In case of child actor BA which A2 was trying to obtain a handle for, who is the direct supervisor of BA ?

Comment: A and B are actors, A1 and A2 are messages of some type A, which requires processor actor to be spawned. Actor A gets A1 (first message of type A), spawns processor actor AA. Actor B gets A2 (second message of type A), and instead of getting already existing processor actor AA, tries to get its own child, BA, and, as it's not there, fails. I want actors to share children per actor class, not instance, i.e. instance B should be possible to get AA processor, which is a child of another instance of the same actor class.

Comment: create an static pool of your child actors and use that in all your instances.

Comment: Well, I was more or less asking about how I do it, while still maintaining ability to supervise them from consumers.